# Syntax error, unrecognized expression Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Hey Guys my fist post at stackoverflow.

i have a small Webservice that delivers json.

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "info": [{
        "URLREST": 0,
        "URLGEPLANT": 0,
        "URLGESAMT": 35
    }],
    "anwesend": "Name 1#Name 2#Name 3#Name 4#"
}
```

In my JavaScript, I have a syntax error. How do I find out if the error is in my Json or my JQuery Code?

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Name 1#Name 2#Name 3#Name 4#
>
> jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:13370

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

        $(data.info).each(function(index,value) {     
            document.getElementById('URLREST').innerHTML = value.URLREST;
            document.getElementById('URLGEPLANT').innerHTML = value.URLGEPLANT;
            document.getElementById('URLGESAMT').innerHTML = value.URLGESAMT;    
        });

        $(data.anwesend).each(function(index,value) {
            document.getElementById('anwesend').innerHTML = value;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `anwesend` is not an array. Why are you using `.each` there ?

Comment: `"anwesend": "Name 1#Name 2#Name 3#Name 4#"` - why isn't this a proper _array_ to begin with? (That's why you are getting the error, too, I suppose - because you are trying to use `each` to "iterate" over a string value. You would need to split that at the `#` characters first - but again, an array would make more sense in this place.)

Comment: Sometimes i have a  knot in my brain. a arry make more sense i will change it now.

Comment: you cant apply each function in a string. convert it using data.info.split(" "), then apply $.each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the last value of **"anwesend": "Name 1#Name 2#Name 3#Name 4#"** is string.

But you have applied the $.each method

```
 $(data.anwesend).each(function(index,value) {
            document.getElementById('anwesend').innerHTML = value;
        });
```

over that string which is not valid.

if you want to make loop over 'anwesend' then you have to send array via api

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "info": [{
        "URLREST": 0,
        "URLGEPLANT": 0,
        "URLGESAMT": 35
    }],
    "anwesend": ["Name 1","Name 2","Name 3","Name 4"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument of `.each()` must be an array or a CSS Selector, but you have `$('Name 1#Name 2#Name 3#Name 4#').each(...`, which is not an array or a correct CSS Selector

Answer (score 0):

The selector you use is invalid for jQuery:

```
$('Name 1#Name 2#Name 3#Name 4#');
```

because it ends with hash tag. Following selector gives no errors:

```
$('Name 1#Name 2#Name 3#Name 4#a');
```

More about the jQuery ID selector [here](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).